# Expectation of the sum of logarithmic Chi-squared variables

Tags: logarithms, expected-value, chi-squared

How to calculate the expectation of the sum of Chi-squared variables:

$$
[log(a_1+b_2)]
$$

where $Y_i$ is a chi-squared variable $\chi^{2}_{2m}$ of 2m degrees of freedom.

Comment: you can expend it a little bit: $[log(a_1+b_2)] = [log(a_1) + log(1 + b_2/a_1)] = [log(a_1)] + E[log(1 + b_2/a_1)]= log(a) + [_1] + E[log(1 + b_2/a_1)]$